# Initial data for Models in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I am loading initial data to some models using initial_data.json . In one of my model I want to store json data . Now my problem is if I try load json data to my model it will give syntex error .

e.g .,

```
{
        "pk": "16443630-d2c5-11e4-8b84-00000000000b",
        "fields": {
            "fk_fact_type": "6a545d1c-cbca-11e4-a17e-000000000007",
            "content":"{"data": "dummy data"}"
        },
        "model": "model name"
    },
```

this content will obvious generate syntax error as I am loading data from json file and `"content":"{"data": "dummy data"}"` is not a valid json. If I'll try to load data as `{'data': 'dummy data'}`  then it is not a valid json .

Any solution how to load initial data for json field from json file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove unneeded double quotes around `content` dictionary:

```
"content": {"data": "dummy data"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this part you want to be stored as a string representing the JSON you want in a single column of the db?:

```
"content":"{"data": "dummy data"}"
```

In that case try escaping the double quotes:

```
"content":"{\"data\": \"dummy data\"}"
```

Otherwise @catavaran is correct if you want the whole thing to be valid JSON.